# How to parse a string into real equation

Tags: r, string, equation

I am trying to convert a string into a real equation. For example: my current string is

```
> a<-"y = 31.563 + 5.923*x1 + 5.061*x2 - 0.662*x3 - 0.381*x4"
> class(a)
[1] "character"
```

Right now, I have a new data set:

```
x1=3 
x2=3
x3=4
x4=7
df_new = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

I would like to get the value of `y` based on the equation. So I need to convert that string into real equation. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: try `eval()` function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably **not** the best way to do this, but `eval(parse(...))` will work:

```
a <- "y = 31.563 + 5.923*x1 + 5.061*x2 - 0.662*x3 - 0.381*x4"
df_new <- data.frame(x1=3,x2=3,x3=4,x4=7)
eval(parse(text=gsub("y =","",a)),df_new)
```

I wasn't quite sure how to get the value returned from `eval()` so I got rid of the `y=` part ...

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Why would you remove yours if this one is accepted? It takes a somewhat different approach using `expression` so it's quite helpful to have both.

Comment: Two answers still make for a pretty clean question. In fact, the number of answers per question is a metric new stack exchange sites are judged on, I believe a 2.5 average is seen as ideal.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I can not accept an answer in 5 mins. Please also respect Stackouflow rules. Feel free to remove anything you want to remove.

Answer (score 3):

In my comment, I mentioned that you can use a function. Well, I will not touch that solution now, but provide you another using `expression`.

```
## define expression
expr <- expression(31.563 + 5.923 * x1 + 5.061 * x2 - 0.662 * x3 - 0.381 * x4)
## sample data
df <- data.frame(x1 = runif(5), x2 = runif(5), x3 = runif(5), x4 = runif(5))
## evaluate your expression in data frame environment 
y <- eval(expr, df)
```

@Ben has used the combination `eval()` and `parse()`, that is another common trick. If you really want to start from a character string `string`, or you are given such a string and has no choice, then you have to do `parse(text = string)` to make it an expression first. My answer really assumes you can input your equation yourself, in which case using `expression` is very good.